# How to overload operator equality for JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have created new objects with Dojo.declare. How to overload operator == for objects ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading Arithmetic Operators in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634341/overloading-arithmetic-operators-in-javascript)

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10539938/632951

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't overload `==`, but `==` has an implicit `.toString()` call, so whatever `.toString()` returns will allow you to effectively overload `==` (kinda):

```
function foo(){}
foo.prototype.toString = function(){ return 42; }

var x = new foo();
x == 42; // true
```

As for how to do this in Dojo, I don't use Dojo, sorry, but the gist is that you get a reference to whatever object is creates and add `thatObject.prototype.toString` as in my example.

Comment: For an object and a primitive, maybe.  Though `valueOf` is what you would want to override.  But not for two objects.  `new String('x') != new String('x')` despite the fact that both objects' `toString` methods return the same value.

Comment: @Mike - meh.  You're right.  Object equality doesn't apply because there is only a check to the memory address...

Comment: even for object and primitive comparison the priority will be given to `valueOf`implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. JavaScript doesn't support operator overloading.

Answer (score 3):

You can't in Javascript/ECMAscript. You can overload operators in ExtendScript from Adobe. See [this example](http://www.indiscripts.com/post/2010/05/operator-overloading-with-extendscript). Also see this [blog entry](http://blog.thejit.org/2009/01/27/why-not-operator-overloading-in-javascript/) (pro), or [this](http://directwebremoting.org/blog/joe/2007/03/22/operator_overloading_in_javascript_2_and_a_potential_monster_csrf_hole.html) (contra).

Comment: This seems to apply to ActionScript only.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: wtf? That's what I said this answer! Adding some links to show there's discussion on operator overloading for ECMAscript.