# Can you avoid repetition in cases like this?

Tags: javascript, syntax, shorthand

I try to avoid repetition in my code as much as possible.
I know you can turn this:

```
variable = variable+2
```

into this

```
variable += 2
```

but how can I avoid repetition here? Surely there is a way...

```
this.className = this.className.replace("classname","")
```

Comment: Well, you can always roll a function that does the job. Then you don't have to write things twice each time.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the answer is no, there is no shorthand for that type of statement.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function to do what you are wanting?  As far as a += I'm not aware of a way to overload the operators in javascript... see

[Overloading Arithmetic Operators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634341/overloading-arithmetic-operators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JQuery you can call

```
$(this).removeClass('classname');
```

Comment: Or indeed in modern browsers `this.classList.remove('classname')` - either way is more reliable than a string replace!

Comment: @bobince This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks man! Too bad I can't mark this as the chosen answer.