# Javascript Adding Objects with +

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overloading Arithmetic Operators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634341/overloading-arithmetic-operators-in-javascript)

Is it possible to add Javascript Objects in a custom way? Javascript allows you to use the `+` symbol to merge `Strings` together as well as add `Numbers` together.

I am wondering if you could define new ways for things to be merged such as adding arrays.
What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
var output = [0,1,2] + [3,4,5];
console.log(output);
//I want this to log [3,5,7]
```

I know I could easily do this with some `addArray()` function but I was wondering if it can be done by using the `+` symbol.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I wrote it as that.

Comment: This sort of thing is more common in functional languages or math packages, which Javascript is neither. In this case, for an imperative language, I think that the expected behavior of `+` is array concatenation.

Comment: `I was wondering if it can be done by using the + symbol` Seems like you already ran this in the console, so you probably have the answer to your question already, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Javascript does not support operator overloading and there is no built-in functionality to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to add Javascript Objects in a custom way?

Yes, you can write your own *addObject* function.

> Javascript allows you to use the + symbol to [concatenate] Strings together as well as add Numbers together.

ECMA-262 defines whether the '+' punctuator is treated as a [unary](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) or [addition](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) operator in expressions. As Mat says, you can't overload it. Even if you could, it doesn't seem like a good idea to change its behaviour since it's already used for 3 different things and has a specified behaviour for "adding" arrays like `[1,2] + [3,4]`.