# addition without using "+"

Tags: javascript, html, addition

Would like to be able to add with a "/" or a "," sign as well as the traditional "+" sign. Obviously the "/" sign is used for division, but I would like to change its purpose.

## JavaScript

```
function CalculateIMSUB(form) {
  var Atext = form.input_A.value;
  var Btext = form.input_B.value;
  var val = form.val.value;
  var A = eval(Atext);
  var B = eval(Btext);
  if (isNaN(A)) A = 0;
  if (isNaN(B)) B = 0;
  var answer = A - B;
  form.Answer.value = answer;
  form.input_A.value = form.input_A.value.replace(/\+/g, ",");
  form.input_B.value = form.input_B.value.replace(/\+/g, ",");
}

function calculateAll() {
  var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
  for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    CalculateIMSUB(forms[i]);
  }
}
```

## HTML

```
<form>
  <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_A" SIZE=15 />
  <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_B" SIZE=10 />
  <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="+" name="SubtractButton" onclick="CalculateIMSUB(this.form)"
  />
  <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Answer" SIZE=12 />
  <input type="hidden" name="val" value="1221" />
</form>
```

[Here's my example](http://jsfiddle.net/qvDFY/14/)

Comment: And what exactly is your question? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634341/overloading-arithmetic-operators-in-javascript) ?

Comment: Can I make:4/2 equal 6 or 4,3 equal 7

Answer (score 2):

Try implementing something like this. No `eval`, just arrays.

```
function add( value ) {
  return value.split(/[+,\/]/).reduce(function( a,b ) {
    return +a + +b;
  });
}

console.log( add('1+1+1') ); //=> 3
console.log( add('2,2,2') ); //=> 6
console.log( add('3/3/3') ); //=> 9
```

Comment: It's just a function that takes a string in the specified format, so you need to grab the values from each input one by one and run them through the function to obtain the result.