# javascript calculator: plus sign alternatives

Tags: javascript, calculator

As I was researching my current question this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634341/overloading-arithmetic-operators-in-javascript) seemed to be promising but I could not figure out for myself if it was the answer to my question. So if anyone could help my that would be terrific.

This is my Function:

```
function CalculateIMSUB(form) {
  var Atext = form.input_1.value;
  var Btext = form.input_2.value;
  var val = form.val.value;
  var A = eval(Atext);
  var B = eval(Btext);
  if (isNaN(A)) A = 0;
  if (isNaN(B)) B = 0;
  var answer = A - B;
  form.Answer.value = answer;
}
```

This is my html:

```
<form>
  <INPUT TYPE=TEXT name="input_1" SIZE=15>
  <INPUT TYPE=TEXT name="input_2" SIZE=10>
  <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="+" name="SubtractButton"
  onclick="CalculateIMSUB(this.form)">
  <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Answer" SIZE=12>
  <input type="hidden" name="val" value="" />
</form>
```

My question:

Can I add with  "/"

For instance currently, if you were to type 10 / 5 in the input 1 text field and click calculate you would have an answer of 2 in the Answer text field. Since as we all know 10 divided by 5 equals 2. I would like to be able to type 10/5 into the input 1 text field and receive an answer of 15 which would be the equivalent to 10+5. Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you and here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvDFY/20/).

Comment: Why would you want to represent addition with division?

Comment: and why is the plus sign there when you're subtracting the numbers?...not sure about overloading the operators, but you could do what you want with a regex

Comment: @Blender the reason I would like to do that is this is for inventory at my work. We use the division sign to represent a different location when we are using pen and paper.

Comment: @groovy, the plus sign is there because in my function. You add everything from the input1 (5+5+5) field and subtract it by everything from the input 2 (2+2+2) field. which would give a result from the numbers I provided in the parenthesis to be 15-6 which is 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do this:

```
var Atext = form.first.value.replace(/\//g,"+");
var Btext = form.second.value.replace(/\//g,"+");
```

Which would replace all division operators behind the scenes so that your eval will process them as addition. (So you could put 5/5/5 and get 15, or what have you.)

Comment: groovy, I believe you just became my new favorite person. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple calculator implementation with prototypes and a module, no `eval` needed.

```
var calc = (function calcModule() {
  function Calculator(operation) {
    this.op = operation;
    this._init();
  }

  Calculator.prototype = {
    _init: function() {
      this.n1 = +this.op.split(/\D/)[0];
      this.n2 = +this.op.split(/\D/)[1];
      this.result = this[this.op.match(/\D/)[0]]();
    },
    '+': function() { return this.n1 + this.n2 },
    '-': function() { return this.n1 - this.n2 },
    '*': function() { return this.n1 * this.n2 },
    '/': function() { return this.n1 / this.n2 }
  };

  return function(op) {
    return new Calculator(op);
  };
}());
```

You can change what the symbols do if you want to. You use it like so:

```
console.log(calc('20-15').result); //=> 5
console.log(calc('15/5').result); //=> 3
...
```

Note that it's very simple, it'll only work with two numbers, but just so you get an idea...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I would imagine it would be impractical for my [website](http://strubeinventory.info/home1.html).

Comment: `eval` will be even more impractical. A user could enter malicious code into any of those inputs... My example is very simple but with a bit of work you can use multiple numbers, plus this is more portable.

Comment: @Clint: Wanna crash your app in just a second? Enter `while(true)` into any input that it's being evaled and click "Master Calculation". BAAANG! That's why `eval` shouldn't be used for this.

Comment: You bring up a very good point. The website I provided is one I use with my tablet to enter inventory at my workplace. I provided the website as an example, I will shortly restrict access to the webpage so that only I can view and or submit forms. I am not a pro by any means so, I ask you if only I am using this would implementing your strategy be a sensible thing to do if I were the only one submitting data. That was what I meant when I said impractical