# Good HTML5 object for mathematical input?

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

For an HTML5/JavaScript learning experience I'd like to write a basic calculator. The first thing I need to know is what options are there in terms of input types which would support only numeric characters, and (if possible) allow the inclusion of operators such as `+` and `-`. The end result would be for the user to be able to input characters in the value range of `0-9`, as well as `{+, -, /, *, ... }`.

Is there anything which is natively tailored to this kind of thing, or at the very least tweakable to something of that nature?

Comment: Yes, there is `eval` and regular expressions. That should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's simple calculator using `eval` and regex:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="calc">
<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var input = document.querySelector('#calc')
  , button = document.querySelector('#calculate');

// Only allow numbers and operators
input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  if (!/[0-9+\-/*]+/.test(key)) e.preventDefault();
});

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(input.value +' = '+ eval(input.value));
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/utujas/1/edit

Some say `eval` is evil, but it's fine for a simple calculator, otherwise you'd have to resort to something like this: [javascript calculator: plus sign alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994946/javascript-calculator-plus-sign-alternatives/14995167#14995167)

Comment: The fact that you use `if (!/[0-9+\-/*]+/.test(key))` makes `eval` perfectly fine here :)