# How to assign logical/math operator to an Object's function?

Tags: javascript, object, operators

So I'm making an expression parser in JavaScript and wanted to know: is there any way to assign an object's function to a logical/mathematical operator so that it gets called everytime the operator is used on that object?

I know that, for instance, whenever you try to concatenate an object to a string it automatically calls the object's `.toString()` method.

For example, imagine you had objects with a `this.number` attribute. I wanted to be able to do the following:

```
function MyObject(number) {
    this.number = number;
}

var obj1 = new MyObject(2);
var obj2 = new MyObject(3);

obj1 *= obj2;
obj2 *= 3;

obj1.number; // Would return 6.
obj2.number; // Would return 9.
```

In this case, I would have overridden the `*=` operator so that everytime it was called to assign a value to an instance of `MyObject` it would multiply the instance's `this.number` value by the value on its right (the primitive number value or the other instance's `this.number` value).

Is there any way of acheiving this?

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620667/javascript-operator-overloading

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `.valueOf()` function to return a numeric value. The runtime will call that in cases analogous to when it decides to call `.toString()` — that is, when it wants to coerce the object to a numeric value.

You cannot, however, force the runtime to treat an assignment specially, so you can't make

```
obj1 *= obj2;
```

work.  The best you could do (with a `.valueOf()` implementation) would be:

```
obj1.number = obj1 * obj2;
```

The `.valueOf()` might look something like:

```
MyObject.prototype = {
  valueOf: function() { return this.number; }
};
```