# Is it possible to define operations in a class, like the __add__ method from python

Tags: javascript, oop

In python there are what's called [data models](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) also known as "underscore methods". In a class these methods allow you to specify the behaviour of your object. For instance you may define the `__init__()` method which is essentially the constructor method. Or maybe the `__add__()` method which defines what operations to do when the `+` sign is called between two object from that class.

Here's an example code in Python

```
class Polynomial:

  def __init__(self, *coeffs):
     self.coeffs= coeffs

  def __add__(self, other):
     return Polynomial(*(x+y for x, y in zip(self.coeffs, other.coeffs)))
```

So the above `__add__()` method defines the `add` operation between two Polynomial objects. In this case it just adds the coefficients of same degree.

My question is: can this be done in Javascript?
Can I define what happens when I do

```
polynomial1 = new Polynomial(1,2,3)
polynomial2 = new Polynomial(2,3,4)

polynomial1 + polynomial2
```

Currently, when writing `polynomial1 + polynomial2`
 in the console, the console returns `"[object Object][object Object]"`

Comment: afaik there is no operator overloading in javascript. You need `.add`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620667/javascript-operator-overloading)

Comment: Is expected result `[3,5,7]`?

Comment: @guest271314 yes but that was just an example