# Is there a way to add or subtract object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

With a vector for example, how would you implement this?

```
const vec = vec1 + vec2;
console.log(vec);

// OR

const vec = vec1 * vec2;
console.log(vec);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620667/javascript-operator-overloading)

Comment: TLDR: you can't, use a method instead.