# moment js subtract'ed date equal another date by <= returns false instead true

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am very much confused by following behavior while comparing two dates:

```
moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
'2022-07-15'
moment(range.end).subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
'2022-07-15'
```

why then:

`moment(date) <= moment(range.end).subtract(1, 'days')`

[image]

what should be the proper way compare this days for date being equal, gt, lt using momentjs?

UPDATE:

using `isSameOrBefore` after having both dates wrapped in moment:

```
date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
'2022-07-15'
range.end
'2022-07-16'
moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
'2022-07-15'
moment(range.end).subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
'2022-07-15'
moment(date).isSameOrBefore(moment(range.end).subtract(1, 'days'))
false
```

I guess I got it:

`moment(date).isSameOrBefore(moment(range.end).subtract(1, 'days'), 'day')`

providing level of granularity of check to day seems to do the trick.

[docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/)

> As the second parameter determines the precision, and not just a single value to check, **using day will check for year, month and day**.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/

Comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/19620667/476

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment gives us [`isBefore`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/), [`isAfter`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/), [`isSame`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/), [`isSameOrBefore`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) etc. to make these comparisons.

```js
var a = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')

var b = moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')

console.log(moment(a).isAfter(b));
console.log(moment(a).isBefore(b));
console.log(moment(a).isSameOrBefore(b));
// sometimes you may want to provide precision level of comparision like this:
console.log(moment(a).isSameOrBefore(b, 'day'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier, but after using `isSameOrBefore` I got even more confused ;( - see the updated question

Comment: `moment(date).isSameOrBefore(moment(range.end).subtract(1, 'days'), 'day')` providing level of granularity of check to day seems to do the trick.