# Overload logical operator with enum typing in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, overloading, logical-operators

I have an enum like this that I use as a type

```
export enum PathDirection {
    ASCENDING="ASCENDING";
    DESCENDING="DESCENDING";
};
```

In some part of my code, I would like to get the opposite path direction as the one I have. Something like this :

```
let myVar = PathDirection.ASCENDING;

myVar = !myVar;
```

Is there any way to overload the logical operator `!` to make this happen ?

Comment: No that's not possible, at runtime your `enum` is a `string`.

Comment: JavaScript has no operator overloading, and TypeScript doesn't like to add runtime functionality like that to JavaScript.  Do you want an answer that just says "no, sorry"? Or are you interested in alternatives like abandoning enums in favor of booleans like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wj1RYW)?

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! No I wanted it to be a string, but if it's not possible, I'll manage to do it otherwise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

JavaScript does not allow you to overload operators. See the answer to [Javascript: operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19620667/2887218) for more information.

Furthermore, TypeScript does not add such functionality to JavaScript.  That would require the compiler to emit different JavaScript for `!xxx` depending on the compile-time type of `xxx`, which would run afoul of [TypeScript Design Non-Goal #5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#5407](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5407) for more information.