# How I can avoid automatic type coercion when comparing numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators, integer-arithmetic, coercion, implicit-typing

I want to know how I can avoid automatic coercion when comparing numbers using the less than and higher than operator in JavaScript.

For example, I already know that == operator makes type coercion, for example:

```
1 == '1'; //true
```

And === operator doesn't, for example:

```
1 === '1'; // false
```

But, how I can avoid this when comparing numbers?, for example:

```
1<2; //true
1<'2'; //true
1<'0'; //false
```

I want to avoid this automatic type coercion.

Comment: You could always do fun stiff like : `typeof a === typeof b && a < b`

Comment: There is no fun on RTTI, but this solution sounds enough (for now)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading Arithmetic Operators in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634341/overloading-arithmetic-operators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use boxing via the RegExp literal. For example:

```js
console.log(/3.1/ > 3);
console.log(/3.1/.exec(3.1) > 3)
console.log((/Infinity/).toString().replace(/\//g,"") > 3)
```

or NumberFormat:

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat({}, {'style':'percent'}).format(2) > 1)
```

**References**

- [A quick tour of JavaScript primitives: Auto-boxing of primitive types – Dave Mac – Medium](https://medium.com/@DveMac/a-quick-tour-of-javascript-primitives-894eceee31c2#35d0)
- [RegExp - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
- [Upcoming Regular Expression Features  |  Web  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/07/upcoming-regexp-features)
- [The State of Internationalization in JavaScript - Blog | SitePen](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2017/07/19/the-state-of-internationalization-in-javascript/)
- [Destructuring Regular Expression Matches in ECMAScript 2015 | Marius Schulz](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/06/24/destructuring-regular-expression-matches-in-ecmascript-2015)
- [Intl.NumberFormat - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)