# ExtJS: Fully functional custom type

Tags: extjs, types, field, extend

I'm looking for the best way to define own custom type in ExtJs.
I would like to use it in forms, grids, pivots, etc., it should has own rendering, calculating and sorting behaviour.

Consider a type 'pace'. Pace is defined as amount of time needed to move on unit of distance, for example pace 2:30 means you need two and half minute to do 1 mile or km.
Pace could be added (2:30 + 2:35 = 5:05) and be used in other calculations.
The smaller pace is faster, that means pace 2:00 is faster (higher) than 2:30.

So far as I know, this is a way to define own custom type and use it in data model as in coding below:

```
Ext.define('App.fields.Pace', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.field.Field',
    alias: 'data.field.pace'
});

Ext.define( 'Data', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 
        {name: 'id'},                           
        {name: 'pace', type: 'pace'}
    ]
});
```

Such defined type is a dummy one, it doesn't render, sort or calculate correctly.

Is there a way to extend it, so it will work ok in forms, grids, pivots, etc.?
What should I do to archive it? Should I define or overwrite some methods?
Or perhaps I should take other similar type (for example date) and inherit it or use it as template? 
I think as minimum the new custom type should provide a method to convert its value to internal type like int and a method to render this internal value as external format but I haven’t find such methods.

Is it possible to define own type which will work correctly in all scenarios where standard type could be used?

Regards,
Annie

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that calculating with custom types is supported in ExtJS. You can extend any class with any function you wish, to implement custom calculation functions, but I am [not sure you can override operators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634341/overloading-arithmetic-operators-in-javascript).

That said, let me give you an example of a custom type `array`:

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.field.Array',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.field.Field',
    getType: function() {
        return "array"
    },
    compare: function(o1, o2) {
        if (!o1 && !o2) {
            return 0
        }
        if (!o1) {
            return -1
        }
        if (!o2) {
            return 1
        }
        if (o1.length != o2.length) {
            return o1.length > o2.length ? -1 : 1
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < o1.length; i++) {
            if (o2.indexOf(o1[i]) == -1) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0
    },
    convert: function(value) {
        if (this.separator && Ext.isString(value)) {
            if (value == "") {
                value = []
            } else {
                value = value.split(this.separator)
            }
        }
        if (Ext.isArray(value)) {
            if (this.map) {
                value = value.map(this.map)
            }
            return value
        }
        return []
    },
    serialize: function(value) {
        if (Ext.isArray(value)) {
            if (!this.allowBlank) {
                value = Ext.Array.filter(value, function(a) {
                    return a !== ""
                })
            }
            if(this.separator) return value.join(this.separator)
            else return value
        }
        return value
    }
});
```

A typical field definition in a model may then be the following:

```
{
    name: "Names",
    type: "array",
    allowBlank: false,
    separator: ","
}
```

which would be able to parse a JSON array or a comma-separated string, and serialize into a comma-separated string for submission, or

```
{
    name: "Attachments",
    type: "array",
}
```

which would be able to parse a JSON array and also serialize into an array, or

```
{
    name: "Categories",
    type: "array",
    separator:',',
    map:function(value) {
        return Ext.create('MyApp.model.Category',{value:value});
    }
}
```

which does take a comma-separated string and map every part of it into a model, so that it returns an array of models.

This value does sort, serialize and deserialize, but not render. Rendering isn't done by a type, but by the `Ext.Component` that uses the type, e.g. the `gridcolumn` or the form field. There's a reason they have a `datecolumn` and `datepickerfield`, a `numbercolumn` and a `numberfield` (AKA `spinner`), a `checkcolumn` and a `checkboxfield`, just to name a few.

For my array, a suitable field would be the `combobox` with `multi:true`, but I need a column with a custom renderer; so let's make an `arraycolumn`:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.ux.ArrayColumn',{
    extend:'Ext.grid.column.Column',
    lines: 6,
    renderer:function(value) {
        if (Ext.isString(value)) {
            value = value.split("\n")
        }
        var len = value.length;
        if (this.lines && len > this.lines) {
            value = value.slice(0, lines - 1);
            value.push('and {n} more...'.replace('{n}', len - lines + 1))
        }
        return value.join("<br>");
    }
});
```

Everything without warranty, of course...

Answer (score 0):

It feels like a bit of an anti-pattern as complex types (or those with rules) are generally modelled separately and such entities can be attached to records using [one-to-one associations](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.schema.OneToOne). With your question in mind however, this is the simplest implementation I could come up with.

[**» Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/196p)

Ideally I'd of liked to normalise and store the values as integers; the lowest denomination of "pace" ***i.e.*** the total number of seconds.  Unfortunately the ExtJS field types don't provide any formatting hooks that work automatically with other parts of the *API* so string manipulation it has to be.

The following field class includes a custom `getValue` function which reduces either a numeric or string input to an integer. The other functions override members of the base class and are called automatically by the framework.

`convert` is called when data is read into the model and is used here to implicitly validate the integrity of the input. `sortType` is called whenever you use the various sorters on collections and is used here to reduce the string to an unambiguous / easily comparable value.

```js
Ext.define('App.data.field.Pace', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.field.Field',
    alias: 'data.field.pace',
    isPace: true,

    getValue: function(v){
        var type = typeof v,
            isNan = isNaN(v);
        if(type === 'number' || !isNan)
            return isNan ? 0 : (+v|0);
        if(type === 'string'){
            var match = v.match(/^(\d+):([0-5]?\d)$/);
            if(match)
                return (+match[1]) * 60 + (+match[2]);
        }
        return 0;
    },

    convert: function(v){
        var proto = App.data.field.Pace.prototype,
            value = proto.getValue(v),
            mins = value / 60 | 0,
            secs = value % 60;
        return String(mins) +':'+ (secs<10?'0':'') + String(secs);
    },

    sortType: function(v){
        var proto = App.data.field.Pace.prototype;
        return proto.getValue(v);
    }
});
```

Note that the all functions are deliberately accessed via the class prototype instead of from the `this` keyword - while playing around it looked as if the framework - at various points - likes to call field functions independently of any (if any) instantiated class, so it's advisable not to rely on the bound context.

In order to address the addition / math on field values you can utilise the `calculate` configuration - though as this is specific to each use-case it should reside within the model that's actually using the custom field type. For example:

```js
Ext.define('App.data.Model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'paceOne',
            type: 'pace'
        },
        {
            name: 'paceTwo',
            type: 'pace'
        },
        {
            name: 'paceTotal',
            type: 'pace',
            calculate: function(data){
                var proto = App.data.field.Pace.prototype;
                return proto.convert(
                    proto.getValue(data.paceOne) +
                    proto.getValue(data.paceTwo)
                );
            }
        }
    ]
});
```