# Adding + to the dictionary in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a dictionary in javascript like this

```
var operations=
{  
  first:     function(x) 
             {
                return x[0];
             }
}
```

How can I add the + operation as key to the dictionary that will point to the + operation in javascript? The same thing was done in python by operator.add . How can do it in Javascript?

```
var operations=
{  
     +    :     return + operation in javascript //syntax is not valid

     first:     function(x) 
                 {
                    return x[0];
                 }
}
```

.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading Arithmetic Operators in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634341/overloading-arithmetic-operators-in-javascript)

Comment: I doubt if it is possible in javascript

Comment: any alternative ways?

Comment: Operators are not functions/objects.. You can not to point to them.

Comment: Alternative is to use own implementation on objects or functions like `(...rest) => rest.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)`

Comment: can u show me how the function will look like, the function to add the items in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"+"`

```
var operations=
{  
     "+"    :     return + operation in javascript //syntax is not valid

     first:     function(x) 
                 {
                    return x[0];
                 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though question is not very clear, but as per my understanding,
use function, like

```js
var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var operations=
{  
     "+"    :    function (x){ return x.reduce(function(p,n,ar,i) { return p+=n }, 0) },

     first:     function(x) 
                 {
                    return x[0];
                 }
} 

console.log("SUM: " + operations["+"](data));

console.log("FIRST: " + operations.first(data))
```

Comment: i just want to get the + operation in javascript.. The same thing done in python by operator.add ...

Comment: '+' operators work in two ways in JS, adding values or concatenation , how will you decide what operation to call

Comment: @A.T.— the [*unary + operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-unary-operators) also does type conversion to number. ;-)

Comment: @Meta_Data check the edited one, to add values in an array