# Is there native support for implementing object arithmetic in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Think of the Date() object:

```
thisDate = new Date()
thatDate = new Date()
thisDate - thatDate //returns some date object
```

Would it be possible for me to make some object, say `Clovers()` such that:

```
theseClovers = new Clovers();
theseClovers.count = 10;
thoseClovers = new Clovers();
thoseClovers.count = 4;

theseClovers - thoseClovers; //returns b = new Clovers(); b.count = 6
```

This is the way I envisage it (but is entirely hypothetical):

```
function Clovers(){
    onSubtract(b){
        if(b instanceOf someClass){
            return this.count - b.count
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a `.valueOf()` function to your objects (or a prototype); it's like `.toString()` except for numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading Arithmetic Operators in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634341/overloading-arithmetic-operators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Clovers(val){
   this.count=val || 0;
}
Clovers.prototype.valueOf=function(){
 return this.count;
};
```

So it would work quite similar:

```
alert(new Clovers(new Clovers(10)-new Clovers(5)).count);
//or long written:
var a=new Clovers(10);
var b=new Clovers(4);
var c=new Clovers(a-b);
alert(c.count);
```

However, it might be better to have a custom addition function for that, similar to Array.prototype.concat:

```
 Clovers.prototype.concat=function(clover){
   return new Clovers(this.count-clover.count);
 };
```

Use like this:

```
var a=new Clovers(10);
var b=new Clovers(5);
var c=a.concat(b);
alert(c.count);
```

Thanks to Pointy and Karl-Johan Sjögren for the ideas...

Comment: I actually prefer the first technique of overloading valueOf(). This is exactly how Date appears to work since `Date()-Date()` actually returns a value. So this is perfect! Thanks for the fish!

Comment: @Sancarn youre welcome ;) . please mark it as answer... and by the way, its not really overloading, its overriding