# Am I witnessing operator-overloading in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operator-overloading

I thought that there was no such thing as *operator-overloading* in JavaScript.

Then I noticed that when using this [BigNumber class](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/), I can actually do subtraction:

```
let a = new BigNumber("5432");
let b = new BigNumber(1234);
let c = a - b;
console.log(c); // 4198
```

How is it possible, or what am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know what makes you think this is operator-overloading, BigNumber returns a number, the docs say that the quotes are because they called a preceding `.toString()`. You're subtracting 2 Numbers here

Comment: I checked it via `console.log(typeof a)` and got `Object`, not `Number`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading Arithmetic Operators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634341/overloading-arithmetic-operators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript doesn't have operator overloading.

`BigNumber.prototype.valueOf` is provided which returns a value. Read up on [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf).

From MDN:

```
function MyNumberType(n) {
    this.number = n;
}

MyNumberType.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.number;
};

var myObj = new MyNumberType(4);
myObj + 3; // 7
```

Comment: I don't understand from your answer, how the expression `a - b` is executed / evaluated.

Comment: Oh, is it `a.valueOf() - b.valueOf()`?

Comment: So then I'm at risk losing precision in that case, right?

Comment: OK, I'll rephrase that: Speculating from the name "BigNumber", I'm at risk losing precision in your **subjective opinion**?

Comment: @goodvibration That library has a `minus` method - why not just use that?

Comment: @General_Twyckenham: I used "-" by mistake, and my code was running flawless. Then I realized that I should have used "minus", so was wondering how come it worked without it.