# Set truthy value of JavaScript custom Object

Tags: javascript

Is there a property from an object that I can modify to specify the truth value for the object. For example add a line inside:

```
var myObj{...}
```

so that I can determine whether  the code block associated with the following if-statement is executed:

```
if(myObj){
    //dosomething
}
```

Something analogous in Python would be overriding the `__bool__` method.

Comment: No, but you can add an i.e: `isTruthy()` method to your objects.

Comment: As you can see [in the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-toboolean), `ToBoolean` always returns `true` for an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript does not have a mechanism to override operations like this.  Objects will always be truthy as defined by the [ECMAScript spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-toboolean) pointed out by Felix Kling.  The closest that I can think of that does something similar to that is the `toString()` method; but there is no `toBool()` method that you can override.

I'm not super familiar with Python, but I'm pretty sure that `__bool__` is basically a way to override how an Object is cast to a Boolean.  I'm comparing that to similar language features like [`__lt__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) which I would also assume is how Python allows you to override certain operators in similar to C++.

It's not directly related, but you should also consider reading this question: [Overloading Arithmetic Operators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634341/691711).

Consider also this excerpt from [2ality's Why all objects are truthy in JavaScript](http://2ality.com/2013/08/objects-truthy.html), emphasis mine:

> The conversion to boolean is different for historic reasons: For
>   ECMAScript 1, **it was decided to not allow objects to configure that
>   conversion**. The rationale was as follows. The boolean operators || and
>   && preserve the values of their operands. Therefore, the same object
>   may have to be coerced several times. That was considered a
>   performance problem and led to the rejection.

Comment: I see, basically since || returns one of the expressions as opposed to returning true or false it would be inefficient?

Answer (score 1):

When you say `if(myObj){...}`in javascript. The condition will be true if `myObj` value is not one of `undefined`,`null`,`0`,`false`, `zero length string` values. so any value except this values makes the condition `true` in javascript.

Comment: check out this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't exist in JavaScript, if you're defining a map then it doesn't make sense to have it behave as a `boolean` value.

For that you can either set a key inside that object to be a `boolean`:

```
let myObj = { isValid: true }

if (myObj.isValid) {
    // do something
}
```

or assign `null` to it in which case you can check for it's validity:

```
let myObj = null

if (myObj === null) {
    // do something
}
```

Also, it would be better practice to check the object against a real value instead of relying on the magic of truthy values as it may result in false result.